# AS3 Dynamic access to a sound channel

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a flash project with many soundchannels active at the same time. I want a little function to play one and loop it, and the name of the sound channel will be passed as a parameter. This is the function:

```
function playBGMusic(channel:String):void
{
    SoundChannel(channel) = bgSound1.play(); 
    SoundChannel(channel).addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, loopBGMusic);
}

playBGMusic("bgChannel1");
```

This doesn't works, flash gives me this error:

> 1105: Target of assignment must be a reference value.

I tried to simplify the function, using an static string only in the listener

```
function playBGMusic():void
{
    bgChannel1 = bgSound1.play(); 
    SoundChannel("bgChannel1").addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, loopBGMusic);
}

playBGMusic();
```

This time it compiles, but it gives me this error:

> Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "bgChannel1" to
>   flash.media.SoundChannel.

How can I access to a sound channel from a string?

Thaks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it in the context of `this`:

`SoundChannel(this[channel])` or `SoundChannel(this["bgChannel1"])`